# How do I play a saved stream from a live application?

Tags: video, stream, playback, wowza

I have an application called "recorder" set to record all incoming streams. It's meant to accept streams, and store them.

The Streaming File Directory is set to `${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/content/recorder`

How do I playback these saved streams by using the same application?

I've tried going to `rtmp://[server-ip]/recorder/[streamname]`, and that doesn't work. I've tried all sorts of combinations of `mp4:[streamname].mp4`, `[streamname].mp4`, `mp4:[streamname]` but those don't work either.

I've only gotten it to work by creating a video-on-demand application, setting the Streaming File Directory to the location that the recorder's Streaming File Directory is set to, and playing the file by accessing that application instead of the recorder.

Can you playback saved streams from a live application, or can you only playback using vod applications?

I've tried following [this tutorial](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?35#playback) but I always get a "Stream not found" when I try to play my streams using the built-in test players through the recorder application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, you can't play a saved stream from a LIVE application.

You can only playback a saved stream from a VOD application, once you set the `Streaming File Directory` to point to the place where the LIVE application saves it's content.

Comment: Wowza Streaming Engine Manager does have a [DVR add on](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?300), which might fit your needs.